# Cannot connect to another computer via Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets

I've been trying to connect to my friends computer across the web.

The server runs with no issue but when my friend runs the client, it just closes.

CLIENT:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((MY PUBLIC IP, 1234))

while True:
    full_msg = ''
    while True:
        msg = s.recv(8)
        if len(msg) <= 0:
            break
        full_msg += msg.decode("utf-8")

    if len(full_msg) > 0:
        print(full_msg)
```

SERVER:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    # now our endpoint knows about the OTHER endpoint.
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection from {address} has been established.")
    clientsocket.send(bytes("OI PEDRONE","utf-8"))
    clientsocket.close()
```

I've tried to change the server's ip to:

```
0.0.0.0
socket.gethostname()
```

Comment: Clearly "127.0.0.1" is wrong; that only listens on your local computer.  You need to bind to "0.0.0.0"   Are you behind a router?  Have you configured the router to pass port 1234 to your computer?

Comment: *" it just closes."* - Are you sure that there is no kind of error message? Please provide it any messages you get. *"server runs with no issue"* - no issue would mean that the server behaves as expected which also would mean that shows that it has accepted the connection from the client - since you explicitly print information about this. Does the server do this?

Comment: As @TimRoberts said, i changed the binded ip from "127.0.0.1" to "0.0.0.0" and forwarded  port 1234 in my router.

Comment: As for @SteffenUllrich, I was testing with my friend running the client python script in his computer on another city, but he was running it by just dubble-clicking it, which means the cmd window just closed when it encoutered an error, when he ran in porperly (i.e "python client.py" on the cmd) he got this error: _TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]._
Also, I've checked if the server is indeed running with "netstat -aon | find '1234'" and it is!
But no clue how to solve it.

Comment: @yut: *"... on another city... "* - am I correct that "MY PUBLIC IP" is not actually the IP address of the computer were the server is running but the IP address of the router connecting your network to the internet? If in doubt, try to bind to it in your server instead of binding to 0.0.0.0 - if it fails it is not the IP address of your system. In this case you would need to have port forwarding on your router so that connections arriving at your router get actually forwarded to your internal server.

Answer (score 0):

Here I put similar server client codes written in python.
The server sends the time every 15 seconds and the client receives it.

**Server Code :**

```
import socket
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 4900))
s.listen(5)
c, addr = s.accept()
print("CONNECTION FROM:", str(addr))
while True:
    dateTimeObj = str(datetime.now())
    print(dateTimeObj)
    c.send(dateTimeObj.encode())
    sleep(15)
c.close()
```

**Client Code :**

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('Server^s ip adress', 4900))
while True:
    msg = s.recv(1024)
    while msg:
        print('Received date :' + msg.decode())
        msg = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```